# 404 page is not showing in nextjs after export

Tags: static, next.js

I've added a custom 404.js file in /pages directory and it's working fine locally but when I run next export and put all files from out directory to public_html directory in cpanel, everythings is working fine but when I enter wrong path it should go to 404 page instead my web takes me to home page with same link in address bar.
For Example: I don't have /about page when I try to go to /about page, my website should show me to 404 page instead it showing me home page (index.html) with /about in address bar.

next.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
  exportPathMap: async function (
    defaultPathMap,
    { dev, dir, outDir, distDir, buildId }
  ) {
    return {
      "/": { page: "/" },
      "/faq": { page: "/faq" },
      "/how-it-works": { page: "/how-it-works" },
      "/patient-onboarding": { page: "/patient-onboarding" },
      "/privacy-policy": { page: "/privacy-policy" },
      "/terms-of-use": { page: "/terms-of-use" },
      "/searched-pharmacy": { page: "/searched-pharmacy" },
      "/new-customer": { page: "/new-customer" },
      "/404": { page: "/404" }
    }
  },
  trailingSlash: true,
}
```

using **"next": "^10.0.6",**

server.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const next = require("next");
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

const sitemapOptions = {
  root: __dirname + "/public/",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "text/xml;charset=UTF-8",
  },
};

// Create the Express-Next App
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();
//Start the app
app
  .prepare()
  //Start Express server and serve the
  .then(() => {
    const server = express();
    // serve sitemap
    server.get("/sitemap.xml", (req, res) =>
      res.status(200).sendFile("sitemap.xml", sitemapOptions)
    );

    server.get("*", (req, res) => {
      return handle(req, res);
    });
    server.listen(3000, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("> Ready on http://localhost:3000");
    });
  })
  .catch((ex) => {
    console.error(ex.stack);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

[on local showing 404 page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jssp.png)

[Same path after deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfaUx.png)

Comment: Just an aside, is there a reason why you're using `exportPathMap` since the export file structure is the same as your folder structure in `/pages`?

Comment: I'm new to nextjs I'm not sure what it's doing so I just put it because I found it somewhere.
But if I remove this it's still not working on production

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At last! I found the solution for my problem.
Thanks to [this document](https://www.sistrix.com/ask-sistrix/onpage-optimisation/http-status-code/4xx-client-error-404-error-page/how-to-correctly-return-the-http-status-code-404-for-an-error-page)

There is no issue in my NextJS configuration the issue was my .htaccess file. I've changed .htaccess file and 404 page is now working with **HTTP status code 404**.

I've just followed these 2 simple steps!

1. Added 404.html file at *root_level*
2. Added this line in .htaccess file `ErrorDocument 404 /404.html`

**Note:**
Both .htaccess and 404.html files are at *root_level*